# theme_table drupal 7 issue - operator not supported for strings in theme.inc

Tags: 7, theming

Although i have found the fix of this problem, but i thought of sharing with others.

Problem is if you mention $rows & theme_table like following:

```
$row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['alt_name']), 'class' => 'alt-ing-name-td');

$output = theme_table(array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows,'attributes' => array('id' => 'recipe-id')));
```

then you will get following error:

```
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in theme.inc
```

Comment: thanks, this saved me a lot of time porting a drupal 6 module to drupal 7

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem you need to mention class & id values in array. 
PFB, the corrections:

```
$row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['alt_name']), 'class' => array('alt-ing-name-td'));

$output = theme_table(array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows,'attributes' => array('id' => array('recipe-id'))));
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Just a note: this isn't exclusive to `theme_table()`, (nearly?) all theme functions that use HTML class attributes expect an array rather than a string in Drupal 7

Comment: +1, You are right. During migration from 6 to 7, i have noticed this.